# SCORM package module when refreshed it asks question New Attempt or resume - How do we stop this message to not come

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

We are getting this message every time user comes to access this SCORM module "New Attempt or Resume".

How can we stop these messages so that they do not appear time and again and user should by default land to resume section.

Can anyone help us with this please.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your course is setting `cmi.exit` (SCORM 2004) or `cmi.core.exit` (SCORM 1.2) before closing the course. If the exit status is not explicitly set, the LMS will use its own logic to infer how a course re-launch is handled.

SCORM 2004 docs state

> If the cmi.exit is set to “normal”, “logout”, ”time-out” or “” (empty characterstring) then the SCOs learner attempt ends.

If you want the user to resume the last attempt, set `cmi.exit` to "suspend".

You should also be explicitly setting the lesson status to "incomplete". Perform a commit afterward to ensure the data is persisted (saved) in the LMS.